# Почему не работает скрипт?

Tags: curl, php

Я в PHP новичок. Собственно вот

```
<?PHP 
$komy = "Alex";
$otkogo = "Vova";
$msg = "Test";

$ch = curl_init('http://*********.ru/msg/text/index.php?action=send&msisdn='.$komy.'&from='.$otkogo.'&msg='.$msg.'&submit=Send');
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Почему не работает скрипт? Исправьте меня, пожалуйста. Или Выдвиньте свой вариант скрипта. Заранее большое спасибо :)

Comment: потому что домен *********.ru не существует:)
приводите полное имя домена - посмотрим.

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? А что вы ожидаете от этого скрипта?

Answer (score 1):

Я честно говоря сам не спец., но попробую помочь. Если Вам не трудно напишите строчку где ошибка, или ошибку не выдает?
Вот пример кода.

```
 <?php
    $komy = "Alex";
    $otkogo = "Vova";
    $msg = "Test";
    // инициализация сеанса
    $ch = curl_init();

    // установка URL и других необходимых параметров
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://*********.ru/msg/text/index.php?action=send&msisdn='.$komy.'&from='.$otkogo.'&msg='.$msg.'&submit=Send');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    // загрузка страницы и выдача её браузеру
    curl_exec($ch);

    // завершение сеанса и освобождение ресурсов
    curl_close($ch);
    ?>
```

Comment: Ребята зачем Вы автора минусуете? Человек задал вопрос, не знаете - не отвечайте.